# Compare column of 2 similar dataframes with un equal rows and replace the value of a column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have 2 similar dataframes with unequal rows.

```
DataFrame 1
------------
    stockname  quantity  purchase_price purchase_date   weight
0       BSHSL        34        102.0000    2020-09-01  0.06172
1     SBICARD         8        804.3410    2020-09-01  0.11863
2   SANGINITA       110         71.2500    2020-09-01  0.13902
3   TOUCHWOOD       218         50.1479    2020-09-01  0.19395
4      SOLARA        12        917.7250    2020-09-01  0.20000
5    SUMICHEM        41        269.8520    2020-09-01  0.20000
6  LIQUIDBEES        14        999.9900    2020-09-01  0.08668

DataFrame2
-----------
   stockname  quantity  purchase_price purchase_date   weight
5  LIQUIDBEES        12          1000.0    2020-06-26  0.25399
```

I am trying to deduct the quantity of Dataframe1 with the quantity of Dataframe2 where Dataframe1.stockname == Dataframe2.stockname. Basically I want to replace the quantity with the difference in Dataframe1

Kindly suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it.
merge the two DF and then subtract the quantity from DF2

```
df['qty'] = df.merge(df2[['stockname', 'quantity']], on='stockname', how='left')['quantity_y'].fillna(0) 
df['quantity'] = df['quantity'] - df['qty']
df.drop(columns=['qty'])
```

OR

using assign , calculating the different from df and df1 quantity and updating it in place, result is same

```
df=df.assign(quantity= df['quantity'] - 
          df.merge(df2[['stockname', 'quantity']], on='stockname', how='left')['quantity_y'].fillna(0) )
```

```
    stockname   quantity    purchase_price  purchase_date   weight
0   BSHSL          34.0     102.0000        2020-09-01     0.06172
1   SBICARD         8.0     804.3410        2020-09-01     0.11863
2   SANGINITA     110.0     71.2500         2020-09-01     0.13902
3   TOUCHWOOD     218.0     50.1479         2020-09-01     0.19395
4   SOLARA         12.0     917.7250        2020-09-01     0.20000
5   SUMICHEM       41.0     269.8520        2020-09-01     0.20000
6   LIQUIDBEES      2.0     999.9900        2020-09-01     0.08668
```